# How to properly use S_ISREG function

Tags: c, stat, readdir

EDIT: After some help from the forum it was made clear that this issue was not in the use of `S_ISREG()` but in my use of `lstat()`. Sorry for the misleading question.

I'm looking in a directory and trying to tell the difference between regular files and sub-directories.

I've looked through other people's issues with this problem, and while some were similar, none were answered clearly enough to fix my code.

```
    int find(char *argv)
    {
        DIR *pointerToDir;
        struct dirent *pointerToDirent;
        struct stat status;
        int mode;

        pointerToDir = opendir(argv);
        if(pointerToDir == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't open that directory (or it doesn't exist)\n");
            closedir(pointerToDir);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            while((pointerToDirent = readdir(pointerToDir)) != NULL)
            {
                lstat(pointerToDirent->d_name, &status);
                mode = S_ISREG(status.st_mode);
                if(mode != 0)
                    printf("%s must be a file\n", pointerToDirent->d_name);
                else
                    printf("%s must be a dir\n", pointerToDirent->d_name);
            }
            closedir(pointerToDir);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I pass the program a test directory that has 2 sub-directories and 2 regular files. The layout would be something like this:

> dir1
>
> > - sub1
> > - sub2
> > - dir1.txt
> > - test.c

Now when I run my program and pass "dir1" as the argument, I would expect it to return the following:

> . must be a dir
>
> .. must be a dir
>
> sub1 must be a dir
>
> dir1.txt must be a file
>
> sub2 must be a dir
>
> test.c must be a file

But instead, it returns that they are all "dirs". What am I missing?

Comment: The names that `readdir()` finds are relative to the directory in which`opendir()`was called. Also: check the return value from`lstat()`, it will probably be `-1`.

Comment: When I checked the return value of `lstat()` it was 0 for "." and ".." but -1 for all others. Do I need to prepend "dir1" to the beginning of the string passed to the `lstat()` command for the sub-directories and files?

Comment: Also, @wildplasser thanks for adding the "stat" and "readdir" tags to the question. I'm still learning how to properly behave in this forum, nice to have experienced folks looking out for us newbies.

Comment: Yes,indeed. (and `.`  and  `..`  are present in *every* directory)

Comment: I did a test scenario using the full path in the `lstat()` command and (predictably) it worked. I still have some work to do to get it to work in my `while()` loop but that shouldn't be too hard. Thanks for your help @wildplasser!

Comment: Also, you can examine [the value of `errno`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5) after a standard call to functions such as `lstat()` or `readdir()` fails to find out *why* it failed.

Comment: You could use `fstatat` instead of `lstat` to avoid the need to manipulate strings.